# Removal of duplicate initialization of variables in constructors

Tags: java

I gave an interview for Java Interview, the panel asked me one question. Code is

```
public class ClassA
{
    int a,b;

    public ClassA(int a)
    {
        this.a = a;
    }
    public ClassA(int a,int b)
    {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }
}
```

They asked me that we have written this code (this.a = a;) two times in our code. So one code should not be written multiple times. How we can write it once and it should work when both the constructors are called?

Comment: but I think this code looks good :)

Comment: check if there is any scope of reusing existing code.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The interviewer mean this

```
public class ClassA
{
    int a,b;

    public ClassA(int a)
    {
        this.a = a;
    }
    public ClassA(int a,int b)
    {
        this(a);   // calling another constructor
        this.b = b;
    }
}
```

Comment: No, we are using this.a = a twice. One in ClassA(int a) and one in ClassA(int a,int b). So he said, no matter what constructor is called. this.a = a must be written in only one line not twice.

Comment: Yeah this can be the answer. what you shown. Do you know any other way of doing it?

Comment: Why would you need yet ANOTHER way when this answers the question?

Comment: id do it the other way around ( calling `this(a, b)` with some default b)

Comment: @Takendarkk I just want to find all possible ways of the given problem.

Comment: @AツGot the solution. Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

Use the setters methods:

```
public class ClassA {
    int a,b;

    public ClassA(int a) {
        this.setA(a);
    }
    public ClassA(int a,int b) {
        this.setA(a);   // calling another constructor
        this.b = b;
    }
    public void setA(int a) {
        this.a = a;
    }
}
```

Comment: You need not to write `this.setA(a);` just `setA(a)` will do. ;)